# Regex match until any characters are found except for the word 'and'

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find a regex solution to match a part of the string after Item Number(s) until any characters are found except if it is the word 'and'

```
s = 'this part 123 should be ignored Item Number(s)92349252 and 30239429434, 124029354,345340332,  234325923 hallo 2121124'
```

it works if I add specifically `hallo`

```
re.match(r'.*?Item Number\(s\)(.*?)hallo.*$', s).group(1)
```

```
'92349252 and 30239429434, 124029354,345340332,  234325923 '
```

however I want it to work for any characters (including `hallo`) except if it is the word `and`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regex just use:

```
a,b,c = s.partition("and")
print(c)
```

c is the part after and.

Comment: I want a general solution in regex, it should also work for `s = 'this part 123 should be ignored Item Number(s)92349252 and 30239429434, 124029354,345340332 and 234325923 hallo 2121124'`

Comment: Try it, this will partition on the first and, will work for both

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a combination of string split with `re.findall`.  First, split the input on the text `Item Number(s)`, and retain the *second* entry in the array.  This corresponds to all text to the right of `Item Number(s)`.  Then, use `re.split` to split on whitespace followed by some content which is *not* either the word `and`, a digit, space, or commad.  Finally, use `re.findall` to capture all numbers from the remaining text.

```
s = 'this part 123 should be ignored Item Number(s)92349252 and 30239429434, 124029354,345340332,  234325923 hallo 2121124'
nums = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', re.split(r' (?!\band\b|[\d\s,])', s.split('Item Number(s)')[1])[0])
print(nums)

['92349252', '30239429434', '124029354', '345340332', '234325923']
```

Comment: ah but the trick is I do not want the numbers after `hallo`, only the numbers between `Number(s)` and `hallo` (or any other character except for `and`).

Comment: @Bruno Check the updated answer.  Your question did not make this requirement very clear.

Comment: thank for the input but I do not want specifically split at 'hallo' but for any characters except if these characters form the word `and`. So for example `123 Item Number(s) 456 and 789 @ 0123` yields ` 456 and 789 `.

Comment: Try the updated answer, which uses `re.split` with your new logic.

Answer (score 0):

I stated the question incorrectly. The correct question is: find a string containing numbers after Item Number(s) until a word is found except if this word is `and`.

Rephrasing: find the string after `Item Number(s)` which have 1 or more digits separated by either zero or more non word character(s) or repeated the word 'and` preceded with a non word character followed by 0 or more non word character(s)

```
import re
s = '123 ignore Item Number(s)92349252 and,,;^and,and;;;30239429434, 124029354,345340332,  and and 234325923 hallo 2121124'
pattern = r'.*?Item Number\(s\)(((\W*?|(\W+?and)+\W*?)\d+)+)'
m = re.match(pattern, s).group(1)
numbers = re.findall('\d+', m)
print(numbers)
```

is

```
['92349252', '30239429434', '124029354', '345340332', '234325923']
```